# Visual Studio 2015 is freezing when writing code in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Every time I attempt to use a C# keyword (such as if, else, continue, break, etc), Visual Studio freezes and displays the following message:

"Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy:
Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete.  If you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage, please report..."

It freezes for about 60+ seconds, and will freeze again as soon I type out another C# keyword.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?  I've scoured the internet and am having all sorts of issues finding a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: well, since you regularly encounter the problem - have you reported it? also: have you tried the usual troubleshooting steps - for example: looking at your system resources during use and reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: Do you have an extensions installed? Has this always happened or did it start happening after a VS or Windows update?

Comment: I haven't reported it yet, it just started today.  I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio and that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Why are you using VS2015 and not a current version?

Comment: First thing I would try is if it makes a difference if you run Visual Studio in safe mode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe

Comment: This is occurring in safe mode as well.  

I look a look into some other options and one option helped for about 10 minutes, but then I ran into the same trouble.  This option is to delete the .suo file when launching the project.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to kill it with task manager and start it up again. This won't delete any saved work, and it should stop any internal Visual Studio Operation. You could create a new text file and copy/paste unsaved code into it so that by killing Visual Studio, you aren't losing anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I found another solution that seems to be working. Unfortunately, it appears that IntelliSense is causing the issue. I went into Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense > and uncheck "Show completion list after a character is typed". This seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: But is that really a solution? IntelliSense is in my opinion such an essential part of the coding experience that I wouldn't call disabling it a feasible solution. You should really consider, resetting your visual studio/machine to go and fix this issue at hand.